# Finding all compact subsets of a given set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $K=\{0\} \cup \{ \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{Z} ^{+} \}$. I know that $K$ itself is compact, because for every open cover there is a finite subcover which must include the open set that contains $0$. $0$ being an element of $K$ is crucial. But I am stuck for finding a criterion to describe all compact subsets of $K.$

Comment: Every subset $L$ of $K$ is compact, except those that contain $0$, and there doesn't exist some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that for $m>n$, $\frac1m\in L$.

Comment: @DonThousand Could you elaborate a little more? Why is it that $L$ should not include 0?

Comment: Which topology on $K$ are you considering in your question?

Comment: @J.-E. Pin Euclidean

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: take $C \subset K$. If $C$ is finite, it is compact. Assume now that $C$ is infinite, so that $C$ contains some of the terms of the sequence $a_n = 1/n$, and possibly zero.

Recall that since $C \subset K$ and $K$ is compact, the set $C$ will be compact if and only if it is closed. On the other hand, regardless of wether $0 \in C$ we know that $C \setminus \{0\}$ can be ordered as a subsequence of the former sequence, i.e. $C \setminus \{0\} = (a_{n_k})_k$. Try to extend what you know about $K$ and $K \setminus 0$, which is the case $n_k = k$.

> If $0 \not \in C$, then $a_{n_k} \to 0$ is a sequence in $C$ but $0 \not \in C$, hence $C$ is not closed and in particular, it is not compact. On the other hand, if $0 \in C$, any convergent subsequence $(b_k)$ in $C$ either contains $0$ or is a convergent subsequence of $(a_n)_n$, and thus $\lim b_k = \lim a_n = 0 \in C$. This shows that $C \subset K$ is compact if and only if $0 \in C$.  If you need to use covers, here's a possible argument: suppose that $0 \not \in C$. Then you should not be able to extract a cover from $\{(a_{n_k},+\infty) \cap K\}_k$ since this covers a finite amount of terms of the sequence (recall that $a_n = 1/n$). If $0 \in C$ and $\mathcal{U}$ is a covering of $C$ by open sets, then we have some open set $U \ni 0$ of the covering which then has to contain all but finite elements of $C$. To extract a finite subcover, pick an element of $\mathcal{U}$ for each point in $C \setminus U$.

Comment: I cannot use sequences argument unfortunately. (We haven't covered it). I figured that all finite subsets should be compact, but not sure about infinite subsets.

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase my hint then :)

Comment: Okay, I think this works now. In the spoiler above I have included two arguments, one using that $C \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded, and the other using covers. The formatting is a bit off, so feel free to ask any questions (but do think about this before looking at the solution!).

Answer (score 0):

If $C \subseteq K$ is a subset then $C$ is compact iff $C$ is finite or $0 \in C$.

Comment: Yes, but why? I understand the finite case but not very sure about the includes 0 case.

Comment: @floridablue in any open cover of $C$ the cover element that contains 0 will contain almost all of $C$. And any set without 0 is discrete and so when compact must be finite.